# Debian not reachable via its hostname in LAN

Tags: debian, networking

My debian is not discoverable via its hostname in my LAN.

I have a couple of other ubuntu machines in the LAN and they are all pingable via their hostnames.

on my debian:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ hostname
raspberrypi
```

on another machine in the same LAN:

```
ping raspberrypi
ping: unknown host raspberrypi
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Ubuntu system has the [Avahi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToZeroconf) daemon running while this is not the case for your Raspberry Pi. Install Avahi to solve the problem:

```
# apt-get install avahi-daemon avahi-discover libnss-mdns
```

Comment: jftr you probably have to use the .local domain, e.g. `raspberrypi.local`

Comment: When/how does Ubuntu run the daemon? I don't see anything called 'avahi' in the output of `ps -x`

Comment: EDIT - run `service --status-all | grep avahi`

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed the hostname try installing samba on the Pi.

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Then try the following from your remote machine:

```
ping newhostname.local
```

And to ssh:

```
ssh pi@newhostname.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Did a remove/install of avahi and insserv as suggested, rebooted the whole shebang. Worked.

If you can ping the IP address from another machine on the network, add the option -a to do a reverse lookup. I myself discovered that there's a max length of 15 chars for hostnames on my router.

```
ping -a 192.168.1.123
Pinging RASPBERRYPI [192.168.1.123] with 32 bytes of data:
...
```

As long as that doesn't tell you a name, thou shalt plough on.